# How to not-abbreviate the source class name in spring-boot's logger name?

Tags: log4j, spring-boot

When I run a spring-boot application, it shows the following log:

> 2014-03-05 10:57:51.702 INFO 45469 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]

The logger name is abbreviated for the following:

> org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean

How can I show the full source class name for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Spring boot uses [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) logging.  You can change the configuration by putting a logback.xml file in your class path.  They have a default [base.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml) which defines the overall configuration and includes their [defaults.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml) file.  Because of where the log pattern is defined you will need to created a file that has a few of the items inside copied.  Here is an example of a logback.xml I created:

```
<configuration>
    <conversionRule conversionWord="clr" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ColorConverter" />
    <conversionRule conversionWord="wex" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.WhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN" value="%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(%5p) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%C){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n%wex"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG"/>
</configuration>
```

And here is an example of a log message using this configuration:

```
2015-06-17 09:02:06.511  INFO 18816 --- [           main] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
```

You can tweak the pattern further if you want.  See [this page](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html) and the PatternLayout section for possible items to include.

You can also use other logging implementations per their [logging documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html) and then configure those as necessary.

UPDATE: As of Spring Boot version 1.3.0 (not released yet as of this edit) you can use logging.pattern.console and logging.pattern.file properties to set the pattern for the default Logback configurations.  See the sample properties file  [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) in their documentation.  NOTE: This link could change as it points to the build SNAPSHOT docs.

Comment: Thanks, that's really great help!

Comment: Sorry, I comes from log4j and not familar with logback. Based on the above configration, how can we show MethodName and LineNumber in the log ?

Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer with a link to the documentation for it.  I am not familiar with it myself but it looks similar to log4j.  Based on the page it looks like you can use L or line for the line number and M or method for the method.  There is also "caller" which looks like it might have both.